# Convert old Android project pulled from git to gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle

I have a project that has been resting on Github since when Eclipse was the official Android development platform.

Now I have switched to Android studio and use that as the main development tool.

I wan to migrate my old project, that I just pulled from Git, to the new gradle build system. But the only way this can be done [according to Googles documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects) is by importing it from Ecplise or exporting it from Eclipse and then importing it again.

I'd rather be done with Eclipse now and try to look for a way to migrate the project that is now pulled to AS to gradle to be able to push a new gradle branch of it.

Can this be done without reinstalling eclipse? If so how?

Comment: According to the link you provided, you could `Import the Eclipse project directly into Studio` NOT `Import the Eclipse project from Eclipse` as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: The projekt is in AS but it is not using gradel. The import through git didn't migrate it to gradle.